# Accessing shared folders via RDP causes a BSOD on the remote host

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp

When i connect remotely to my xp-sp3 box, i get a BSOD on the remote host every times i try to access the shared folders i get a bsod on the remote host

The log says:

```
System Error  Error code 1000007e  Parameters c0000005, 00000000, f612c1a8, f612bea4

*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck 1000007E, {c0000005, 0, f5b2a1a8, f5b29ea4}

Probably caused by : rdpdr.sys ( rdpdr!RxLowIoCompletionTail+33 )
```

now, rdpdr.sys is the Microsoft RDP Device redirector... why it would cause a bsod when accessing a shared folder?

Comment: Belongs on SuperUser.

Comment: belongs on superuser? 1. superuser is not active yet; 2. RDP is way more common on servers than on normal computers

Comment: i wiped the disk, reinstalled xp, and the problem is still there....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is COMODO antivirus.....